# getting error - 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED' while running app on xcode 15

Tags: node.js, flutter, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I'm trying to run my app on xcode 15 but getting this below error in metro terminal -

```
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
{
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Also getting this error in xcode -

```
rsync: link_stat "/Users/____/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

I'm using pod version 1.13.0, node version 16.20.0

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two solutions for this issue :

**Solution 1:**

Use an up-to-date version of Node.js, and also use packages that are up-to-date with security fixes.

For many people, the following command will fix the issue:

`npm audit fix --force`

**Solution 2:**

In your **package.json**: change this line

I apologize for the confusion. On Stack Overflow, you can use triple backticks to create code blocks with syntax highlighting. However, JSON is not typically highlighted. For your specific request, you can format it like this:

```json
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

to

```json
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
```